# How to remove video slicing on Agora Cloud Recording and save the long video as single video recording without slicing on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage, agora.io

How to remove video slicing on Agora Cloud Recording and save the long video as a single video recording without slicing on Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in Start Api Client Request

```
"recordingFileConfig": {
              "avFileType": [
                "hls",
                "mp4"
              ]
            },
```